# What is the difference between self.functionName and this._functionName?

Tags: javascript, function, knockout.js

I have a `function` with name as `func1` in knockout JS.

What is the difference between calling the `function` inside `ViewModel` as `this.func1 = function(){}` and `this._func1 = function(){}`?

Are both the same, or is there any difference?

Comment: Function with `underscore` are private function or property in JavaScript...[private property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Private_Properties)

Comment: @SarjanDesai Not quite correct I think. It may be used as a naming convention for private variables at times, but the underscore has no actual *meaning* in JavaScript. In OP's code `_func1` is a publicly visible member of it's enclosing function (not private), despite the underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ***no* meaningful difference whatsoever** between this:

```
function ConstructorFunctionX() {
   this.func1 = function(){};
}
```

And this:

```
function ConstructorFunctionX() {
   this._func1 = function(){};
}
```

They are just different names (with or without underscore) for a member that is accessible to consumers of the constructor function.

This one *is* different:

```
function ConstructorFunctionX() {
   var _func1 = function(){};
}
```

But not because of the name starting with an underscore, but because `this` is omitted, thus allowing callers outside `ConstructorFunctionX` *no* access to the function.

Comment: @RoyJ You are very right, a mistake for sure. I've corrected my answer accordingly.